# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token n" in Express Node Server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I get this error-

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n
    at parse (/Users/afroza/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /Users/afroza/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
    at invokeCallback (/Users/afroza/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
    at done (/Users/afroza/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/afroza/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:308:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I creating a route with nodejs and I'm getting this error,I've tried many things and there's no way, always appears this error,

my server setup in express framework-

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express()
    , fs = require('fs')
    , path = require('path');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'
    , config = require('./config/config')[env]
    , mongoose = require('mongoose');

var http = require('http');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/orbitax');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // add body-parser for interact with server and client data


var jsonParser = bodyParser.json(); //join this body parser with json file

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false});


//Initialize Models
var models_path = __dirname + '/app/models'
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach(function (file) {

  require(models_path+'/'+file)
});

require('./config/routes')(app,config);

var server = app.listen(9000, function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

});
```

server routing,

```
var async = require('async')
    , mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , uploadModel = mongoose.model('uploadModel');


module.exports = function (app) {


  // upload routes

  var upload = require('../app/controller/upload');

  app.get('/newUpload', upload.newUpload);

  app.post('/create_new_directory', upload.create_new_directory);


}



exports.create_new_directory = function(req, res)
{
    console.log("hello")
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

and from client side request is,

```
$http({'method': 'post', 'url': '/create_new_directory', data: $scope.directory })
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data)
            })
            .error(function(){

            })
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of $scope.directory when this $http call is made in your angular app?

Comment: in client side I just the value "new" but in server site It print undefined.

Comment: See my answer below. You'll need to JSON.stringify() your data if it is a string.

Comment: okay, now Its working, the solution is, 
var mydata = {
 data : $scope.createNewDirectory
}
So, my variable declaration was just wrong.

Comment: Great, glad you were able to get it working. Please accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to it so others will know it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `$http` service will only transform request data to a JSON string if the data is an object.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.8/src/ng/http.js#L292

In your case, the request data is a string so it is not getting wrapped in quotes, making it invalid JSON.

You should be able to modify your `$http` config like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/create_new_directory',
    data: $scope.directory,
    transformRequest: JSON.stringify
}).success(function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```